# Filtro en array

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, filtro

Tengo 2 tablas *profesores y *asignaturas el caso es que quiero filtrar que cada profesor tenga su asignatura.
Como puedo fitrar por el *profesor_id, me lo paso desde el fragment al activity por un Bundle al activity DetProfesor?

El Json:

```
{
results_asig: [
{
id_asignatura: "1",
nom_profesor: "Cristian Cavero Garcia",
nom_asignatura: "Musica",
img_fondo: "musica.jpg",
profesor_id: "1"
},
{
id_asignatura: "2",
nom_profesor: "Paloma Faus",
nom_asignatura: "Ingles",
img_fondo: "ingles.jpg",
profesor_id: "2"
}
]
}
```

El model:

```
data class ModelAsignaturas (

        val id_asignatura: String,
        @SerializedName("nom_asignatura")
        val nom_asignatura: String,
        @SerializedName("img_fondo")
        val img_fondo: String,
        val profesor_id: String
    )
```

El activity:

```
class DetProfesor : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.teach_details)



        val bundle = intent.extras
        val idProfesor = (bundle.getString("id_profesor"))
        val nomProfesor = (bundle.getString("nom_profesor"))
        val mail = (bundle.getString("mail"))
        val img_profesor = (bundle.getString("img_profesor"))

        tv_NomProfesor.text = (nomProfesor)
        tv_mail.text = (mail)

        Picasso.get()
            .load(Constants.URL_IMAGES + img_profesor)
            .fit()
            .into(civ_profesor)

        val apiClasi = Api000.getClient.getAsignaturas()

        apiClasi.enqueue(object : Callback<ModelResult> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ModelResult>, t: Throwable?) {
                // Log.e("TAG Fallo: ", t.toString())
            }

            override fun onResponse(idcall: Call<ModelResult>, response: Response<ModelResult>) {
/*                for(res in response.body()!!.results){
                    Log.d("xxx TAG Respuesta: ", res.nom_asignatura)
                }*/

                Picasso.get()
                    .load(Constants.URL_IMAGES + response.body()!!.results_asig[0].img_fondo)
                    .fit()
                    .into(iv_imgFondo)

                rv_details.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext, 2)
                rv_details.adapter = null

                val result = (response.body()!!.results_asig)

                rv_details.adapter = DetailProfesoresAdapter(result.filter { it.equals(idProfesor) })

                println("xxx" + idProfesor)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

El adaptador:

```
class DetailProfesoresAdapter(val asignaturas: List<ModelAsignaturas>): androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailProfesoresAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var context: Context? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.teach_row, parent, false)

        //Log.d("Tag xxx: ", result)

        context = parent.context

        return ViewHolder(layoutInflate)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = asignaturas[position]
        holder.bind(item)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{

            //Toast.makeText(context, "settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

/*            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("nom_profesor", item.nom_profesor)
            bundle.putString("img_profesor", item.img_profesor)
            bundle.putString("mail", item.email)

            context!!.startActivity(Intent(context, DetProfesor::class.java)
            .putExtras(bundle))*/
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return asignaturas.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "LogNotTimber")
        fun bind(asignaturas: ModelAsignaturas) {

            Picasso.get()
                .load(Constants.URL_IMAGES + asignaturas.img_fondo)
                .resize(50, 50)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(itemView.iv_imgFondo)

            //Log.d("Tag xxx: ", asignaturas.profesor_id)

            itemView.tv_namProf.text = asignaturas.profesor_id
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solucion despues de 2 dias.
En el activity;

```
val result = (response.body()!!.results_asig)
                    .filter { it.profesor_id == idProfesor }
```